# How do i execute SQL statements from an SQL file in Scheduler in TYPO3?

Tags: sql, database, typo3, scheduler, statements

The concept:

I have a task which imports some data on the database. The database schema can be changed at any time since it is exported to a folder. So i have to read the database file and create the structure. I would like to do it with TYPO3 API. Before TYPO3 9 i would do something like that:

```
$sqlQueries = explode(';', file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'myFile.sql'));
foreach ($sqlQueries as $sqlQuery) {
    $sqlQuery = trim($sqlQuery);
    if (!empty($sqlQuery) && $this->db instanceof DatabaseConnection && method_exists($this->db, 'sql_query')) {
       $this->db->sql_query($sqlQuery);
    }
 }
```

How do i do that with TYPO3 10?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 10 has already such functionality and you can find it in the **maintenance** module unter the
**Analyze Database Structure**. Thanks to [Mathias Brodala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6812729/mathias-brodala) i found my solution. (It can always be improved).

In your task you call the **SqlReader** class in order to extract the statements from the SQL file. The use namespace is the following (As of TYPO3 10)

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Schema\SqlReader;
```

Now we have two problems with that

1. The SQL evaluated and executed by TYPO3 is limited to schemas. For content changes you need a 3rd party library/tool.
2. It only creates tables and doesn't drop them by default.

The first "problem" it says that you can only perform database structure changes but not the content in it. For that, one could use the **QueryBuilder**.

The second problem is that the **getCreateTableStatementArray** function in the **SqlReader** class does the following:

```
return $this->getStatementArray($dumpContent, '^CREATE TABLE');
```

This calls the **getStatementArray** function and it only returns the CREATE TABLE commands. So if you have a DROP TABLE command in the SQL file, it won't be taken into consideration. For that, we need to create our own function for the **getCreateTableStatementArray**. So in your Task, create this function:

```
/**
 * @param string $dumpContent
 * @return array
 */
public function getCreateTableStatementArray(string $dumpContent): array
{
    $sqlReader = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(SqlReader::class);
    return $sqlReader->getStatementArray($dumpContent);
}
```

With this, TYPO3 will not evaluate the statements by command name and it will get all the commands available in the sql file.

Now that we have done that, we need to pass the statements into our custom function to be parsed. So somewhere in your code you get file's content. I have it like this:

```
/**
 * @return bool
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function execute()
{
  ...
  $this->createTableStructure();
  ...
}

protected function createTableStructure()
{
    $connectionPool = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class);
    $sqlStatements = $this->getCreateTableStatementArray(file_get_contents(__DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'myFile.sql'));
    foreach ($sqlStatements as $sqlStatement) {
        if (strpos($sqlStatement, ' CHARSET=utf8') !== false) {
            $sqlStatement = str_replace(" DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", "", $sqlStatement);
        }
        $connection = $connectionPool->getConnectionByName('Default');
        try {
            $connection->executeUpdate($sqlStatement);
        } catch (DBALException $e) {
            //Your log here
        }
    }
}
```

For this part i got an error that TYPO3 could not read the DEFAULT attribute so i had to remove it.

```
if (strpos($sqlStatement, ' CHARSET=utf8') !== false) {
   $sqlStatement = str_replace(" DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8", "", $sqlStatement);
}
```

This looks like this in the SQL file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myTable`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `myTable` (
  `myColumn1` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `myColumn2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `myColumn3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `myColumn4` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `myColumn5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Hope it was helpful!

Best regards